# matplotlib: put legend symbols on the right of the labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

It's a simple thing but I've searched for quite a while without success: I want to customise a figure legend by *reversing* the horizontal order of the symbols and labels.

In Gnuplot, this is simply achieved by **set key reverse**. Example: change `x  data1` to `data1  x`. In matplotlib, there seems to be no user-friendly solution. Thus, I thought about changing a kind of handle anchor or just shifting the handle's position, but couldn't find any point to start with.

Comment: I don't recall ever coming across this ability (but that doesn't mean it's not there!)

Comment: I suspect that if were a single option, the logic for it would be around L663 in matplotlib/legends.py.  You should create an issue on github requesting this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requested feature is already there, as the keyword `markerfirst` of the `legend` command.

```
    plt.plot([1,2],[3,4], label='labeltext')
    plt.legend(markerfirst=False)
    plt.show()
```

If you want to make it your default behaviour, you can change the value of `legend.markerfirst` in `rcParams`, see [customizing matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is actually a new feature since [matplotlib 1.5](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/whats_new.html#new-plotting-features).